# Swift: Creating Objects on runtime utilizing String for name

Tags: swift

My current instructor insists that the proper way to initialize an object during runtime is as below:

```
class Person {
    var name: String; var age: Int
    init(name: String, age: Int){self.name = name; self.age = age}}

func CreatePerson (person: String, personName: String, personAge: Int){
    var \(person) = Person (name: personName, age: personAge)

CreatePerson(person:"Confused",personName:"Coder",personAge: 35)
```

Needless to say it is not quite so simple.  `\(person)` in the `func Create Person` appears to solely be a String thing.

Sorry to bother you guys with what appears to be a simple process, but "That's how it's supposed to work" really isn't furthering my swift capabilities.

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Answer (score 2):

Your instructor was wrong. First of all, what you showed was not valid Swift code. It will not compile. Second, he/she should teach you how to write *readable* code. In a professional environment, the person who wrote the code won't be the person who modifies it years later.

This is the *most common* way to initialize an object:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

let person = Person(name: "John Smith", age: 42)
```

Obviously there are many others, depending on the situation and personal style.